# How to call an application in Bash using an argument with spaces

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a bash file which is passed arguments which contain spaces. The bash file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
another_app "$1"
```

However, instead of processing the argument as a single argument, as I believe it should, it processes it as a number of arguments depending on how many spaces. For example, if I call my bash file such:

```
my_app "A Number Of Words"
```

Then the "another_app" application gets passed 4 different arguments, instead of one. How can I just pass the single argument through to the second application?

Comment: If `myapp` is that two-line script, then `my_app "A Number of Words"` will call `another_app` with a single argument.  What `another_app` does with that single argument is anyone's guess.

Comment: It's what I thought as well, but I seriously doubt "another_app" has issues with this - it is a very popular command line tool.

Comment: Well, this code will **not** split up the first argument into separate words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The others are correct it will depend somewhat on how the 2nd app handles the args.  You can also have a little control as to how the args are passed. You can do this with some quoting or using the "$@" var as mentioned by @steve

For example app1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo "Argument with no quotes"
./another_app.sh $1

echo "Argument with quotes"
./another_app.sh "$1" 

echo "Argument with \$@"
./another_app.sh "$@"
```

and another_app.sh 
    #!/bin/bash

```
echo "Inside $0" 
echo "Number of args passed to me: $#"

for X in "${@}"
do 
  echo $X 
done
echo "Exiting $0"
```

Comment: You (and @Steve Vinoski) are right. "$1" was working correctly - it turns out the problem was in a different argument passed to the second app wasn't being escaped correctly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Call the second application using `"$@"`:

```
#!/bin/bash
another_app "$@"
```